# How to search in a string to find a pattern

Tags: r, regex, string, stringr

How would I go about finding the longest sequence of vowels?  For example:

```
string <- " asdiubvodjehbuoiewndhwbksh"
```

The output should be `uoie`, the longest sequence of vowels.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could extract all the characters that are a vowel, with `str_extract_all`, return the one with the `max`imum number of characters (`nchar`)

```
library(stringr)
pat <- '[aeiou]+'
out <- str_extract_all(string, pat)[[1]]
out[which.max(nchar(out))]
#[1] "uoie"
```